# How to make an image pop-up on screen without opening another window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have made a simple game where there is a bunch of pictures onscreen and when you click them, you get a point. Here is the code for that:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    picturesRemoved++;
  });
});
</script>
```

Then I also have this later in the code:

```
var picturesRemoved = 0;
```

and this for the pictures:

```
<br><p><img src="test.jpg" border="0" width="1001" height="159"></p>
```

What I want is so that the pictures will keep popping up on the screen until you click a certain amount of them. The certain amount should be 20. I can use CSS, or JavaScript, or HTML, or jQuery. (Or all.)

Thanks!

Comment: so if someone click at 20 pictures, the pictures would be removed?

Comment: no. They would just stop popping up.

Comment: Your current code hides the image.

Comment: Yeah. I know. I want it to hide the image when you click on it. But then more pop up.

Comment: popping up like a kind of lightbox?

Comment: honestly, I don't know what that is. (don't tell anyone.)

Comment: yeah. I just looked up what a lightbox is, and yeah, that's kind of what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML example:

```
<div class="cut_oak_tree">
  <img src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png" onclick="myFunction(this)" /> 
  <img src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png" onclick="myFunction(this)" /> 
  <img src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png" onclick="myFunction(this)" /> 
</div>
<div id='countervalue'>0</div>
```

And Javascript:

```
var inter;

$(document).ready(function(){
    inter  = setInterval(function(){
        $('.cut_oak_tree').append('<img src="http://www.pbpixels.com/x/images/oak.png"onclick="myFunction(this)">');
    },1000);
});

var counter = 0;

function myFunction(img) {
    counter++;
    document.getElementById('countervalue').innerHTML = counter;
    img.onclick = null;
    img.remove();
    if(counter === 20){
        clearInterval(inter);
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nd2w3/2/

Comment: @DownVoter
**When should I vote down?**

Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

Comment: I know when to use my votes, the OP is nothing with the code you've posted. Since when do they have `<yourImg>` tags? Ok you showed how to add and remove an element, but this counts only for 1 element. Your fiddle is fine, so update your code on SO.

Comment: so.... It works on jsfiddle, but when I copy it and paste it, it doesn't work at all. If I click the pictures, they still disappear, but no more appear. Also, the counter div says NaN.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a good javascript programmer, But I know you can use this code to make the element visible or invisible. You can zet the default property of all images to `display:none;` in css. And for the javascript:

#### Invisible

```
document.getElementById(picture").style.display="none";
```

#### Visible

```
document.getElementById("myP").style.display="inline";
```

Comment: but wouldn't that hide all pictures?

Comment: Yes, but then you can set the pictures you want visible vible with `document.getElementById("myP").style.display="inline";`

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addImage() {
            $('body').append('<p class="click-me" onclick="onImageClicked(this)"><img src="test.jpg" border="0" width="1001" height="159"></p>');
        }
        function onImageClicked(s) {
            $(s).remove();
            if (++document.picturesRemoved == 20) {
                clearInterval(document.myInterval);
            }
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.picturesRemoved = 0;
            document.myInterval = setInterval(addImage,1000);  
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

//for jquery mobile probably//

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {
        $( ".photopopup" ).on({
            popupbeforeposition: function() {
                var maxHeight = $( window ).height() - 60 + "px";
                $( ".photopopup img" ).css( "max-height", maxHeight );
            }
        });
    });
   </script>
```

//after that, in html make a button or link like this//

```
<a href="#my_image" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline"><img src="img_folder/my_image.jpg" alt="my image"></a>
```

//place your image like this//

```
<div data-role="popup" id="my_image" class="photopopup" data-overlay-theme="a" data-corners="false" data-tolerance="30,15">
<a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
```

Comment: I just noticed something: in your jquery, you wrote <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: @CaptainBudderChunk jQuery is simply a library for javascript, an extension. The language is still javascript. The `<script>` tag defaults to javascript if none is specified.

Comment: maybe mistake maybe not, but my point just in case to not getting else with other script!!!

Answer (score 0):

A method to do this is to use an "on mouse over" action in html.

Within the script tag:

```
<script>
function large(x) 
{
    x.style.height = "640px";
    x.style.width = "480px";
}

function normal(x) 
{
    x.style.height = "50px";
    x.style.width = "50px";
}
</script>
```

Within the image tag:

```
<img onmouseover="large(this)" onmouseout="normal(this)" border="0" src="x" alt="x" width="50" height="50">
```

NB: x = your image name